# How to combine qt(necessitas) with SDL on android?

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk

I am using Qt on android through necessitas port.
I'm trying to combine Qt with SDL.
When compile such project with SDL invoked (SDL_Init) , compiler gives me error : multiple definition of `JNI_OnLoad'.

LOG : /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.n0n3m4.droidc/files/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.1/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/lib/libSDL.a(SDL_andvideo.o): In function `JNI_OnLoad':
SDL_andvideo.c:(.text+0xddc): multiple definition of`JNI_OnLoad'
qtmain_android.o:qtmain_android.cpp:(.text.JNI_OnLoad+0x0): first defined here

Is there some short way how to solve this ?

specific : compiling on C4droid (ide from google play with gcc , necessitas Qt(gui + core) , SDL plugin)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should ask the developer of c4droid. Looks like he's a helpful guy. He says on google play you should contact him if you have trouble.

Comment: thanks for the answer. in meantime i switched to necessitas opengl & native sound so i dont need SDL. i contacted him about other stuff and  i confirming your state that he is helpful. thanks again